# Como chamar duas animações em um elemento que utiliza ":hover"?

Tags: css, animação

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #885053;
}

#hide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background: #fe5f55;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: hideSlideDown 0.5s forwards;  
  animation: hideSlideDown 0.5s forwards;

}

#tudo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#headbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 254px;
  background: green;
}

#btnmenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#btnmenu:hover{
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;  
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;

}

@-webkit-keyframes hideSlideDown {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 265px;
  }
}

@keyframes hideSlideDown {
  from {
    top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    top: 45%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from {
    top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    top: 45%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    top: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
  <div id="head">
    <div id="hide">

    </div>
    <div id="btnmenu">
      <span>Menu</span>
    </div>
    <div id="headbar">    
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Estou tentando fazer a div **#hide** acompanhar o botão até o centro da página ao apontar para o botão, mas não sei o que está dando errado.

Comment: A div que está com height 0px não está aparecendo na animação.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo pra resolver justamente o que você precisa

```css
.hover-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #191d20;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #197117;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.child2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgb(246,131,32);
  margin: 20px;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.hover-container:hover .child1 {
  background: rgb(246,131,32);
}

.hover-container:hover .child2 {
  background: #197117;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-container">
  <div class="child1"><div>
  <div class="child2"><div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua animação "hideSlideDown" não vai funcionar corretamente, pois ela possui duas declarações distintas. Para fazer a animação do botão você poderá usar [transition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) que é mais simples neste caso.

Caso você queira duas animações no estado hover de um elemento use apenas uma animação com propriedades e valores em [keyframes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes) distintos (10%, 35%, 75%) ao invés de usar "from" e "to", que são equivalentes a 0% e 100% .

Comment: Então como eu vou dizer ao keyframe que a div tem que seguir o botão no hover?

Comment: Então, basta você chamar a animação ou transição dentro do estado :hover do elemento.